# Firebase dynamic object key

Tags: firebase, angularfire

So I want the key in my firebase database to be dynamically generated.

At the moment, I have something like this

```
  whatever.$add({
      title: $scope.formData.title
   })
```

UPDATE: The `whatever` is actually a `$firebaseArray`, and yes, returns an id.

Actually, in the above example, I wanted to do something like:

```
  whatever.$add({
      $scope.formData.type: $scope.formData.title
    })
```

I basically want the key set to something that'll come from a form. Any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm supposing that `whatever` is actually a `$firebaseArray` and if i'm right your `$add` will always result in a new child with random id.

If you want to create a new child with a custom id you should be working with `.child().set()`:

```
   var ref = new Firebase(yourFirebaseUrl);
   ref.child(customId).set({
      type: $scope.formData.title
   });
```

Update:

To have the `$scope.formData.title` as the id you should do:

```
   var ref = new Firebase(yourFirebaseUrl);
   ref.child($scope.formData.title).set({
      type: $scope.formData.title
      anotherData: $scope.formData.anotherFormData
   });
```

Comment: Okay, using the `$scope.formData.type` cause the error, `create.controller.js:37 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .` referring to the `.` in the `$scope.formData.type`

Comment: @Rexford if you want $scope.formData.type to be the id you should replace the `customId` to `$scope.formData.type`.